# Classification of ssh flows in network trafic

Tags: networking, ssh

My task is to detect ssh flows in the network . Now I am observing ssh flow with wireshark . And I can easily see all ssh flows starts like,  "SSH-......". 
An example:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.4p1_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20100308\x0d\x0a
```

I want to ask if my observation is correct , does all ssh flows starts with "SSH- ......" . And also I am searching through RFCs, why I can't verify my observation in any documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All SSH flows start with the server presenting its banner to the client.  You can see this banner with a simple `telnet server 22`.

The format of this banner (properly called the "identification string") is described in [RFC 4253 s4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2), and it always starts `SSH-`, followed by the software version, then another hyphen and the software version.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Checking a information from valid documentation makes me feel safe while implementing it.